# Combined tab view and split view

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, tabs, splitview

I’m working on an app which combines a tab bar controller with a number of split views, so that each tab item shows a different master-detail view. I want the tab to be visible at all times so the user can switch directly between master-detail views.

I can achieve this by having a separate split view for each tab, but I'm not sure whether this is approved by Apple. The view controller catalogue for iOS says "A split view controller must always be the root of any interface you create." However the UISplitViewController API reference says "Although it is possible to install a split view controller as a child in some other container view controllers, doing is not recommended in most cases."

As an alternative approach, I can have a split view as the root, with a tab controller on the primary. This means though that the tab is hidden on compact width devices when the detail view is shown. The user has to navigate back to the master view to switch tabs. This is not the behaviour I want and is not what happens with the Apple Music app for example.

So, a couple of questions:

1. Would Apple reject the app if it has a tab as the root and multiple split views?
2. Is there another way of achieving what I want?

Many thanks.

Comment: A little confused. "Would Apple reject the app if it has a tab as the root and multiple split views?" – didn't you just say that they will in the second paragraph?

Comment: Thanks Andreas. I've added some detail from the Apple guidance as one section is less explicit than the other.

Answer (score -1):

1. Your quote says "not recommended", not "your app will be rejected".
2. The only wishes you have expressed are "I want the tab to be visible at all times so the user can switch directly between master-detail views". That doesn't really leave room for alternatives. Also, you haven't described your app. It might be that your design choice is not suitable for its use cases.

It sounds like you want us — a third party — to speculate about whether Apple would reject your app. This is not the right forum to ask for that, but I say try, and you'll get a definite answer.

Comment: Thanks again Andreas. I'm a little reluctant to do a lot of work on the app only to have Apple say it doesn't meet the guidelines, but as you say that's the only way to get a definite answer. I just wondered if anyone on here has experience of how rigorously the "recommendations" are enforced.